# String length without loop and builtin function

Tags: c++, c, string

How would i find out the length of a string without using loop and String class function like strlen() ?

Comment: Try to guess it, then. :) Do you mean a char array or `std::string`, btw?

Comment: You can use recursion, if you do not want to use loop :)

Comment: In `C` or `C++`? Make up your mind

Comment: `int getLength(const char* str){ return 4;}`

Comment: I guess the easiest way is to ask somebody else to code it for you

Comment: remember it from when you read it in the first place

Comment: May I just ask why? Because this sounds too localized.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan::can you please write it in answer instead of comment , so that i can accept it . Thanks a lot brother .

Comment: @Learner: No, I can't because the question has been closed. I have voted to reopen but it needs more votes

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan::Thanks for your nice post brother . Now i came to know that there is a place for learning in stackoverflow too .

Comment: @Learner: Posted as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int length (const char* p) 
{
    return *p == 0 ? 0 : 1 + length(p+1);
}
```

Any iterative function can theoretically be implemented recursively and vice versa.

Comment: But a loop is just a jump, and CALL is just a JMP with the program address pushed on to the stack...

Comment: @Aslai: a loop is a loop and a function call is a function call. Otherwise everything is simply 0s and 1s

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's true. My biggest worry is that this could have a fatal outcome if the string length is greater than `RAM / BitWidth` though. If the computer only has 1GB of RAM on a 32 bit system, and you have a string that's 214748365 characters long...

Comment: @Aslai: That's true, but it still beats Luchian's approach :)

Answer (score 4):

Subsequent `if`s?

```
if (str[0] == 0) return 0;
if (str[1] == 0) return 1;
///keep going until fingers start bleeding
```

Comment: your using the built in `operator[]` function.

Comment: It doesn't *really* deserve up votes, but it made me laugh so hard :D +1

Comment: @ahenderson make sure the generator does not have loops.

Comment: @Andreas really? And how would you do it without a cycle :P ;) Oh crap back to the basic problem :D

Comment: Just as a proof of concept - can't this be modified with some template magic to actually work for infinite string lengths?

Comment: @ahenderson Well, in that case you're screwed, because *any* read from memory will require some sort of dereferencing, which would be a built-in by your convention.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Right, just wanted to add that to my comment :D

Comment: @paul23 no it cannot be made to work for infinite anything, if by working you mean "at least finishes compiling".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit does `operator*` count as a built-in?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: On a pointer? Nah not a "built-in function". So if you have a C-string then you can trade `str[n]` for `*(str+n)` and get an upvote ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit aren't they equivalent? Also, I don't want a reverse of a vote - I've exactly 91930 rep, why would I trade a nice, round number for 91938?

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to say that if `str` is already a C-string then you're already safe :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ah, but I was assuming `str` is a `char*`.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()

{
    char string[50];

    int i, length = 0;

    printf("Enter a string \n");
    gets(string);

    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        length++;
    }
    printf("The length of a string is the number of characters in it \n");
    printf("So, the length of %s = %d\n", string, length);
}
```

Comment: I have mentioned "Without loop" in my question .
Please read the full question before posting .